# Super Expression Error in React Native Project

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using React Native on OS X, and coding with the Deco IDE.

I'm getting a `Super expression must either be a null or a function, not undefined` error in the simulator on save on my project.

My main issue seems to be from following tutorials online that seem to have a different sort of syntax than what is now used. And unfortunately the people online aren't listing their version. For instance they seem to be leaving out a ton of their commas, whereas my files are requiring it.

Here's a screenshot of the error
[image: error on project save]

And here's the code for the only two files I've edited...

index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import ViewContainer from './app/components/ViewContainer';

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <Text>{'Hello from inside ViewContainer'}</Text>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00a0f0',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

ViewContainer.js file:

```
import { Component, View } from 'react-native';

class ViewContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = React.Stylesheet.create({

  viewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },

});

module.exports = ViewContainer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **ViewContainer** Component Update it to be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class ViewContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  viewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },

});

module.exports = ViewContainer;
```

1- Import React and import **Component** from **react** not react-native

2- there is misspelling in **StyleSheet** is should be UpperCase, and import it from react-native

Comment: You saved my life. There definitely seems to be a syntax difference between what I'm watching and what I'm actually doing. Are you aware of any up-to-date tutorials on React Native?